# How to get total value from Calculate Member MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I wanted store Total from Weekly variance(1.238.232,00) .

because i there is different value on MTD and WTD.

My Calculated Member is

```
     "[Variance(by plan qty) Absolute ]" = ABS(Plant QTY - Actual Qty)
     "[Weekly Variance  (by plan qty) Absolute ]" = SUM(WTD([Date].[Calender].Currentmember),[Measure].[Variance(by plan qty) Absolute])
```

the value wanted is 1.238.232,00 (like picture below)

if i change the value into MTD the value became 40.500,00.

Can I store the Total "Weekly Variance  (byplan qty) Absolute " based Plant,Material ,and Month Year like picture below?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by store? Store in the report? Store in the SSAS database?

Comment: Store on SSAS Calculate Member